# PHP Ignore & operator?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm passing a form which consists of user-submitted values. I understand that you can never trust the user to do the right thing, but this isn't what the question is about. One of these fields requests for a streaming link, such as from www.twitch.tv. Unfortunately, these strings have an & in them.

I've determined that the variable is getting truncated when it reaches an &. I've debugged this by checking what the value is in the JavaScript, and then checked it once it reaches the PHP file via a POST method and AJAX. It seems as if the PHP is reading the & as the reference operator, at least I think it is. I'm not completely proficient in AJAX but the PHP side of things seems to be what's effecting it. I've tried altering the variable in multiple ways but it just seems like PHP doesn't want to get past the operator.

So in short my question would be is there any way to get around the & operator truncating my variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GET method in your form you should consider moving to POST.

```
<form method="post">
...
</form>
```

And change your code to manage $_POST vars instead of $_GET.

Comment: I think he might still have the problem after POSTing those variables?